# Zoom in Stack with children

Tags: flutter

Do you know if and how to make a Stack zoomable - with items like draggable widget.

I have looked at using matrix transformation from [matrix_gesture_detector](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector) but unable to make it work inside a stack. The problem is that it is the Stack that scales and not the items within the stack?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: MatrixGestureDetector(
        onMatrixUpdate: (Matrix4 m, Matrix4 tm, Matrix4 sm, Matrix4 rm) {
          setState(() {
            matrix = m;
          });
        },
        child: Transform(
          transform: matrix,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: myStack()),
        ),
      )

      );
  }

    Widget myStack() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          left: 100.0,
          top: 150.0,
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 100.0,
          top: 300.0,
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you post more details with code? It is not clear what you mean by `make a Stack zoomable`. Do you want to just increase stack area when zooming or do you want to zoom each element in stack while zooming?

Comment: `Transform` inside `Stack` works just fine - you can scale and translate the matrix as you wish

Comment: Ok, so you are able to make the stack are bigger and stack children(widgets) smaller when pinching/zooming out?

Comment: tried `Transform` widget inside `Stack`'s children? if so, what does not work?

Comment: 5 min. I will update my question with some code - good to here you can do it

Comment: Just updated my question, hope it explains it better

Comment: `return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.identity()..scale(2.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.access_time, size: 200),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );`

Comment: I'm confused, as I've tried your code and it works. Is your issue that when pinching from outside the content the zoom doesn't work?

Comment: @JoãoSoares Really, so you dont get the same result as on the picture?The Gray box is the stack, and I need the content of the stack to zoom and not the Stack itself. So the Red and green boxes zooms and not the gray Stack.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your problem. Thank you for clarifying. So you want the grey background to stay in place and only zoom in on the red and green boxes?